# cumulative function in query wont group by

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to reset the cumulative count for every kind of insurance_status. right now my code brings back a cumulative count but does not start over when the insurance_status changes.
how can I set the query to group by or reset variable to get the query I want.

I have tried to add group by right before the last order by in the code, it did not work.

```
SELECT t.insurance_status, t.day, t.vendor_count,
       @running_total:=@running_total + t.vendor_count AS cumulative_sum
FROM (SELECT insurance_status,
             DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y %m') as day,
             count(insurance_status) as vendor_count
      FROM vendor_report_jll
      WHERE project_id in (100, 92, 45, 91, 86, 87, 88, 40, 101, 90, 98)
      GROUP BY insurance_status,day
     ) t JOIN
     (SELECT @running_total := 0) AS t2
ORDER BY  t.insurance_status;
```

[image]

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: The answer is in the question you need to detect a change and zeroise or accumulate running_total if found.

Comment: @P.Salmon mysql version is 8.0.16

Comment: You should check out window functions in mysql - which are much neater than using variables.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

You need another variable to remember the insurance status:

```
SELECT t.insurance_status, t.day, t.vendor_count,
       (@sum := if(@is = t.insurance_status, @sum + t.vendor_count,
                   if(@is := t.insurance_status, t.vendor_count, t.vendor_count
                     )
                  )
       ) AS cumulative_sum
FROM (SELECT insurance_status,
             DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y %m') as day,
             count(insurance_status) as vendor_count
      FROM vendor_report_jll
      WHERE project_id in (100, 92, 45, 91, 86, 87, 88, 40, 101, 90, 98)
      GROUP BY insurance_status, day
      ORDER BY insurance_status, day  -- just being explicit
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @sum := 0, @is := -1) params;
```

You need to do the assignments all in a single statement.  This is due to the rules of MySQL -- it does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`, so you cannot assign variables in one expression and use them in another.